# How to draw a graph by using CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have to draw a graph  by using stock prices in APPLE or SAMSUNG data in CVS file by using Python language.SAMSUNG and APPLE data saved in separate files in same folder.

Desired interface like this [Desired Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8eng.png) If user select Samsung or APPLE in check box.(Only one can select at a time and draw,If I select Apple then Samsung is disabled)Then draw a graph between Date vs Open and Close by selected types from getting suitable CVS file in that folder.In here I give sample data set of apple.csv,it look likes as follows and Samsung data set also like this;

```
Name,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
AAPL,02 Jan 2017,115.82,115.82,115.82,115.82,0
AAPL,03 Jan 2017,115.8,116.33,114.76,116.15,28781800
AAPL,04 Jan 2017,115.85,116.51,115.75,116.02,21118100
AAPL,05 Jan 2017,115.92,116.86,115.81,116.61,22193500
```

I am newer to this language So anyone,please give any guidance to do this task.So please If anyone can give to correct guidance path to do this,it will great help for me.

Code is I have tried:(But this is not correct because I want to selected column to draw Date vs. Open and Close)

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  csv
dateOfx=[]
open_price_y1=[]
close_price_y2=[]

with open('E:\\Project\Data set\\apple.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots =csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for column in plots:
        dateOfx.append(int(column[2]))
        open_price_y1.append(int(column[3]))
        close_price_y2.append(int(column[5]))

plt.plot(dateOfx,open_price_y1,close_price_y2 ,label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Open')
plt.ylabel('Close')

plt.title('Share Market Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Look at a [examples in the matlplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and choose one that looks like what you want as a starting point to creating your own.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound I added my tried code.Actually i do not know how to add selected row column.I am newer to language.Please give a help

Comment: Also int(column[1]) doesn't convert to date. You need to use `date` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

In python the index of an array start from `0`, hence the code was reading the values wrongly. Please try the below code:

```
for column in plots:
    dateOfx.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(column[1], '%d %b %Y'))
    open_price_y1.append(int(column[2]))
    close_price_y2.append(int(column[4]))
```